# Can I make an outer argument the same as an inner argument?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that returns the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below the number passed in. I immediately recognized the similarity to "FizzBuzz". This is the first codewars challenge. I have created two functions that I have tested and they work independently, but I can't figure out how to reference the argument of the outer function *solution()* in my inner function *returnNumber*. Every time I try to run the function, I get an answer of 0.

```
  function solution(number){
   
    function returnNumbers(number){
        
        let numbers=[];
            for (let i=1; i<number; i++){
            if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) numbers.push(i);
            else if (i % 3 == 0) numbers.push(i);
            else if (i % 5 == 0) numbers.push(i);
    } //end of for loop
    return numbers
} //end of returnNumbers
    let sum = returnNumbers().reduce(function(a, b){
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
    return sum 
} //end of solution
```

I already tried assigning a new variable for the original argument but maybe I didn't do it correctly. Like this:

```
  function solution(number){
   let x = number
    function returnNumbers(x){
        
        let numbers=[];
            for (let i=1; i<x; i++){
            if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) numbers.push(i);
            else if (i % 3 == 0) numbers.push(i);
            else if (i % 5 == 0) numbers.push(i);
    } //end of for loop
    return numbers
} //end of returnNumbers
    let sum = returnNumbers().reduce(function(a, b){
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
    return sum
}
```

I imagine the solution is simple, but I am an absolute beginner (< 3weeks) so I would appreciate some help.

Comment: You are not passing `x` value, try `let sum = returnNumbers(x).reduce(function(a, b){
        return a + b;
    }, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

The main issue you are facing is scope - how long a variable still "exists".  The main thing to realize is that anything in the outer function is still in scope in the inner function, as long as you don't declare a variable with the same name (when you do, the outer variable is *shadowed* - it still exists, you just can't access it, because when you use that name you'll get the inner one).

So, your first solution is correct, except that you need to *not have an argument to the function*:

```
function returnNumbers(number){
```

should just be

```
function returnNumbers(){
```

because *number* is already in scope, but if you declare it as an argument, you will need to pass it (but that's pointless in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the quick respose Dave, this worked and is super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

when calling `returnNumbers` function, argument is not getting passed. Try passing the outer function value to it.

```
let sum = returnNumbers(number).reduce(function(a, b){
    return a + b;
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner function already has access to the outer function's parameter (because it's sitting inside of the outer function's brackets). So in your case, `returnNumbers` can *already* use `number` without having it passed as a parameter.

By declaring it as a parameter for `returnNumbers`, you're [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the `number` variable. You have two possible solutions.

Either pass `number` to `returnNumbers`

```js
let sum = returnNumbers(number).reduce(function(a, b){
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
```

Or remove `returnNumbers` parameter

```js
function returnNumbers(){
...
}
```